# Convert chemical equations/ formulae into latex format?

Tags: equations

Is there any OCR Engine (similar to Mathpix for maths) which can convert chemical equations & formulae into latex formulae? The equations would be present either in pdf documents or as image files.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I'm afraid there is not. However, it is not difficult to use something like [`chemfig`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf).

Comment: chemfig for structures.  chemformula for equations